# Richfaces 4 Datatable with onclick Event on row

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a simple Richfaces 4 `<rich:dataTable>` with some `<rich:column>`s.

Now I want if I press on one row, that below the table the ID of the row should be displayed.

Here is what I did so far:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{placeholder_control.lichtList}" var="licht" width="100%" id="lichtListe" columns="2">
<rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Beschreibung" />
            </f:facet>          
            <h:outputText value="#{licht['beschreibung'].stringValue}" width="20" />
            <a4j:ajax immediate="true" event="onclick" render="testingID" listener="#{placeholder_control.selectActiveLight}">
                <f:attribute name="rowKey" value="#{licht['id'].stringValue}" />
            </a4j:ajax>             
        </rich:column>
...
...
<h:outputText value="This is the id : #{placeholder_control.selectedLight}" id="testingID"></h:outputText>
```

The managed bean `placeholder_control` looks like this

```
@ManagedBean (name="placeholder_control")
@SessionScoped
public class ControlPlaceholder {

public void selectActiveLight(ActionEvent evt) {
   String selectedRow = (String) evt.getComponent().getAttributes().get("rowKey");
   System.out.println("Selected Light : " + selectedRow);
   setSelectedLight(selectedRow);
}
```

Everything will be rendered correctly, but if I click on the row (on this column), nothing happens. I also tried to put a non existing method (on purpose) to the listener. I hoped that I get an error message but nothing happend.

If I look at the HTML source code, there is nothing with `onclick` at that `<td>` element.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score -1):

hi friend take a look to rich:extended datatable, i used it to do a task that meet your requirements.
here is the showcase for richfaces 4 and explains the use of extended datatable: http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky
cheers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow scox. This is not a concrete answer to the OP's problem. Please post a more direct/helpful answer. Cheers